# Laravel Eloquent relationship (5 tables)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, laravel-8

I have 5 tables in a database

1. **Volume**: id, volume, number,...
2. **Papers**: id,volume_id,title,...
3. **Editor_name**: id,idP(Papers ID),name...
4. **Email**: id, idA(Editor_name_id), email
5. **Institution**: id, idA(Editor_name_id), institution

And I would need to display all info about article (data from all tables) in one blade.
Example
URI : `papers/{paper_id}`

Volume 1 Number 1
Title 1
Editor_name1, email 1, email 2, institution 1
Editor_name2, email 3, institution 2, institution 3
...
**Migrations:**
Volume:

```
Schema::create('volume', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer("volume");
        $table->integer("number");
        $table->timestamps();       
    });
```

Papers:

```
Schema::create('papers', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string("title");            
        $table->integer("volume_id");            
        $table->foreign('volume_id')->references('id')->on('volume')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
```

Editor_name:

```
Schema::create('editor_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer("idP");
        $table->string("name");
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('idP')->references('id')->on('papers')->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

Email:

```
Schema::create('email', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer("idA");
        $table->string("email");
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('idA')->references('id')->on('editor_name')->onDelete('cascade');;
    });
```

Institution:

```
Schema::create('institution', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer("idA");
        $table->string("institution");
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('idA')->references('id')->on('editor_name')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

**Models:**
Volume:

```
 public function names()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Names::class, Papers::class,'issue','idP','id','id',);
}
public function papers()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Papers::class,'issue');
}
```

Papers:

```
public function volume()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(Volume::class,'issue');
}
  
   public function names()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(EditorName::class,'idP');
   }
```

Names:

```
public function papers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Papers::class,'idP');
}

public function email()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Email::class,'idA');
}
public function institution()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Institution::class,'idA');
}
```

Email:

```
 public function names()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Names::class,'idA');
}
```

Institution:

```
 public function names()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Names::class,'idA');
}
```

Comment: This seems like a very simple request. Have you made any effort to solve this problem on your own? Do you understand the basics of Eloquent relationships?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all information like this way :

```php
public function show($paper_id) {

     $data = Papers::with('volume', 'names', 'names.email', 'names.institution')->findOrFail($paper_id);

     dd($data);
}
```